# Flutter web app should launch a URL and then navigate to another screen

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter project.

I have an issue only when launching the web app.

There is a button that opens a URL on another browser tab:

```
  ElevatedButton(
                onPressed:(){
                  _launchUrl;
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()),
                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false

                  );
                },
                child: Text('pagarpedido'.tr()),
              ),
```

Here you have `_launchUrl()`:

```
Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
    throw 'Could not launch $_url';
  }
}
```

The issue is that when clicking on the button, the app is pushing MyHomePage(), but not opening the expected URL on another browser tab.

Removing the Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil function from the code, when the button is clicked, the expected URL is opened on another browser tab.

What I need is ot click the button and after that to open the URL on another browser tab and the web app should show MyHomePage().

Comment: Have you tried using `await` on the `_launchUrl`?

Comment: @Eternity, no, let me try